# Cannot boot to usb, because ubuntu grub

Tags: grub2

So, i want to boot in to my usb, but when i click to boot to usb, it just bypass it and goto the grub menu
I tried to configure my bios so it goes to usb first and harddisk, still not working

My usb content is Ubuntu Live CD

Answer (score 0):

is your USB bootable or you just copied the contents of Ubuntu Live CD? your usb should become bootable with some application, like startup disk creator in ubuntu.

Comment: Bootable usb content